# WPF - styling a lookless control: How to access dependecy properties of control from second level of ControlTemplates?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, controltemplate, itemscontrol, templatebinding

I am extending the `ItemsControl` (`class EnhancedItemsControl : ItemsControl`), because I want to add several dependecy properties to it - like `AlternativeContent` which will be displayed when there are no items in collection (think of 'enter a search terms and hit search' label in a itemscontrol for results of search).

I have subclassed `ItemsControl` and added an `AlternativeContent` dep. property of type `FrameworkElement` to it. Now I want to provide default style in Themes/Generic.xaml (I have added `ThemeInfoAttribute` to AsseblyInfo, and provided metadata in static costructor as said in this [excellent tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37326/Lookless-Controls-Themes.aspx)).

The style contains a `ControlTemplate`, and I need to use second `ControlTemplate` inside of ItemsControl template, where I add a `ContentPresenter` that should show the `AlternativeContent`.

Now, my problem is how do I tell the `ContentPresenter` that it should take its content from the top-level `EnhancedItemsControl`? If I were inside style's `ControlTemplate`, I would use:

```
 Content="{Binding AlternativeContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

but as I am in `ItemsControl`'s `ControlTemplate` inside style's `ControlTemplate`, this obviously doesn't work, I'd need to refer not to parent template, but to grandparent template, however, `TemplateBinding` doesn't have the `AncestorLevel` parameter.

I also tried:

```
 Content="{Binding AlternativeContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type WPFControls:EnhancedItemsControl}}}"
```

but that results in empty `ContentPresenter` as well. I cannot name the `TemplatedParent` (because it is outside the `ControlTemplate`), so I cannot refer to it by name. I cannot use `TemplatedParent` `RelativeBinding`, because that doesn't reach over two levels of controltemplates. And `RelativeSource` `FindAncestor` strangely doesn't work.

Any idea how to solve this? Thank you!

Generic.xaml (excerpt):

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type WPFControls:EnhancedItemsControl}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type WPFControls:EnhancedItemsControl}">
     <ItemsControl
      x:Name="RootItemsControl"
      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
      ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
      >
      <ItemsControl.Template>
       <ControlTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer
         x:Name="ContentScrollViewer"
         CanContentScroll="False"
         >
         <StackPanel
          x:Name="InnerPanel"
          >

          <ItemsPresenter 
           Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=InnerPanel}"
           MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=InnerPanel}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           />

          <ContentPresenter 
          Content="{Binding AlternativeContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type WPFControls:EnhancedItemsControl}}}" 
          >
           <ContentPresenter.Style>
            <Style>
             <Setter Property="ContentPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
             <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger 
              Binding="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=RootItemsControl}"
              Value="0">
               <Setter Property="ContentPresenter.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
              </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
           </ContentPresenter.Style>
          </ContentPresenter>
         </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
       </ControlTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.Template>
     </ItemsControl>

    </ControlTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
 </Style>
```

Control code:

```
 public class EnhancedItemsControl : ItemsControl
 {

  static EnhancedItemsControl()
  {
   DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(EnhancedItemsControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(EnhancedItemsControl)));
  }


  public FrameworkElement AlternativeContent
  {
   get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(AlternativeContentProperty); }
   set { SetValue(AlternativeContentProperty, value); }
  }

  // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for AlternativeContent.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
  public static readonly DependencyProperty AlternativeContentProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("AlternativeContent", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(EnhancedItemsControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

 }
```

Usage (a `List<string>` is provided as `DataContext`):

```
 <WPFControls:EnhancedItemsControl Height="120" x:Name="EnhancedCollection"
  >
  <WPFControls:EnhancedItemsControl.AlternativeContent>
   <WPFControls:CenteredLabel>
    Alternative content
   </WPFControls:CenteredLabel>
  </WPFControls:EnhancedItemsControl.AlternativeContent>
  <WPFControls:EnhancedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
   </DataTemplate>
  </WPFControls:EnhancedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </WPFControls:EnhancedItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, my bad,

```
Content="{Binding AlternativeContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type WPFControls:EnhancedItemsControl}}}"
```

actually works (but my markup was more complicated than the one in example, and the content was not shown because of other bug...)

Comment: That's an extremely cool piece of work, I'm delighted you've shared it. I wonder will it work on my WP7 phone...